# Tell if a .gz file is really gzipped

Tags: file-format, gzip

What is a nice command-line trick to tell if a `.gz` file is really gzipped, as opposed to being a non-Gzip file just named that way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `file` command to do this. It will look at the magic numbers in the file and tell you what type it really is.

Comment: Although it works I feel like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 7):

If it is gzip'd the first two bytes are 0x1F and 0x8B.

To get more complicated than that you will need to understand the file format.
See here: http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html and go down to "Member header and trailer" section where you can identify a gzip by its 10 byte header.

Comment: Interesting info. But it feels like something that were supposed to be on the program with a verify option or something like that.